# Scapy DNS Request

Tags: python, dns, scapy

I'm trying to write a script in Python with Scapy that makes a DNS Request and receive a DNS response.
This is what i wrote:

```
packet = IP(dst="1.1.1.1")/ICMP()
res = sr1(packet)
if res:
    print "---------------------------------------"
    print "Host is Up, trying DNS Query"
    print "---------------------------------------"
    packet = IP(dst="1.1.1.1") / UDP() / DNS(rd=1, qd=DNSQR(qname="www.google.com"))
    sr1(packet)
else:
    print "Destination Unreachable!"
```

When i run this piece of code, the ping (ICMP) works and receive a response, but when it sends the DNS query it says:

```
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets.
.....................................................................
```

And it keeps printing dots, until i stop it and it prints: "Received 83 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets".

Do you know how to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: have a look at the doc: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#dns-requests**

With the latest scapy version, I cannot replicate :/
The code you posted works
[image: SR1 DNS Example]

A few things that might help you:

- use the latest dev version: the releases are very slow to come. Download it here https://github.com/secdev/scapy/archive/master.zip and install via `python setup.py install` (sudo on Unix)
- try to manually specify the interface (using `iface=...` in `sr1`). The full list is available with `get_if_list()`
- check your firewall. It may be blocking the packets

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I downloaded the dev version of scapy and also used another network connection, now it works.